# Find finite atlas for give torus

Tags: calculus, manifolds

> Given the torus $M=\{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-a)^2+z^2=b^2\},0<a<b$ find a finite atlas

my attempt
M can be written as $M=\{z=\pm\sqrt{b^2-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-a)^2}\}$ and therefore defining the charts
$r_1,r_2$ from $V=\{\sqrt{b^2-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-a)^2}\geq0\}$
$r_1(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{b^2-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-a)^2})$,$r_2(x,y)=(x,y,-\sqrt{b^2-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-a)^2})$